# csv and checkbox in listview save checked checkboxes code in ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-checkbox, savestate, android-savedstate

I am using in my listview a get csv file function. I have already linked this to my Arrayadapter. I have inside my xml for listview 3 textviews for the csv and a checkbox. For every line from the csv it will be created a checkbox. I wan't save the checkbox states if clicked and call them back after refresh, closing etc.

[image: see picture]

`Thats's my single list item

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cbSomeCheckbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

  //the 3 textviews are for my csv file
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="LVL"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/score"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cbSomeCheckbox"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/score"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvSomeText"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.499" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSomeText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

That's my ArrayAdapter

```
package com.example.customlist;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class ItemArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String[]> {

private List<String[]> scoreList = new ArrayList<String[]>();

static class ItemViewHolder {
    TextView name;
    TextView score;
}

public ItemArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
}

public void add(String[] object) {
    scoreList.add(object);
    super.add(object);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.scoreList.size();
}

@Override
public String[] getItem(int position) {
    return this.scoreList.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ItemViewHolder viewHolder;
    if(row == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_list_item, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ItemViewHolder();
        viewHolder.name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name);
        viewHolder.score = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.score);
        row.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ItemViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    String[] stat = getItem(position);
    viewHolder.name.setText(stat[0]);
    viewHolder.score.setText(stat[1]);
    return row;
}
}
```

Comment: didnt get your question

Comment: sry, i have add a picture and have change my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an ArrayList to save position or id of csv (item of listview) that user check.( if you have any issue, feel free contact me: nhat.thtb@gmail.com)
Eg:

```
        holder.cbDelete.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (null != mCallBack) {
                    if(isChecked){
                        mListIDChecked.add(id);
                    }else if(mListIDChecked.contains(id)){
                        mListIDChecked.remove(id);
                    }

                }
            }
        });

        if( mListIDChecked.contains(id)){
            holder.cbDelete.setChecked(true);
        }else{
            holder.cbDelete.setChecked(false);
        }
```